# Php while Loop error in a Array, connecting to Postgresql Database

Tags: php, arrays, database-connection, while-loop

I have a static code to update some select boxes.

The original structure code:

```
$result = "
      ({ 
        'options': [
          {'value': '','description': '(pick an item)'}, 
          {'value': 'test','description': 'test'}, 
          {'value': 'test_2','description': 'test_2'}
        ]
      });
    ";
```

I'm trying to make this dynamic and connect to my table in Postgresql Database but my code don't works.

Here is My Code:

```
if($value=="asus"){

    require("includes/connection.php");

    $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM mapa_ferias WHERE area = 'Asus' " );
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sth->execute();

    $result = "
    ({
      'options': [";

            while($row = $sth->fetch()) { 
            $result += "{'value': '" + $row['nome'] + "','description': '" + $row['nome'] + "'},";
    }

    $result += 
            "]
        });
    ";
  }
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not try to build JSON data yourself.. PHP has a function for it: [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
if ($value=="asus"){

    require("includes/connection.php");

    $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM mapa_ferias WHERE area = 'Asus' " );
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sth->execute();

    $options = array();
    while($row = $sth->fetch()) { 
        $options[] = array(
            'value' => $row['nome'], 
            'description' => $row['nome']
        );
    }
    $sth->closeCursor();

    $result = '('.json_encode(array(
        'options' => $options
    )).')';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Excelent solution.